# AXIOS withCredentials not working in server.js

Tags: spring-boot, express, axios, csrf

I have server.js as proxy to make call to Spring boot -Java. When I am trying to set withcred true in server.js it is not getting the CSRF cookie however its working fine when I am making call directly from React js.

```
    app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
const transport = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true
  })
var https = require('https');
  axios
    .get(
      url+'/token',{
      },
      {
      headers: {
            
        }
      }
    )
  .then(response => {
          res.send(response.data);
              })
                  .then(response => {

                      })
                          .catch(error => {
                            res.redirect('/error');
        });
 });
```